# Linear Regression with NuML

Tags: c#, machine-learning

I'm trying to do a really basic linear regression (Z = 2 * X + 1) prediction using NuML. Given the data is so linear I can't understand why the predicted value is so far off unless I am doing something wrong. I have the target class

```
public class Sample
    {
        public float V { get; set; }
        public float X { get; set; }
        public float Y { get; set; }
        public float Z { get; set; }

        public Func<float, float, float, float> OutputStrategy { get; set; }
        public Sample(Func<float, float, float, float> outputStrategy)
        {
            OutputStrategy = outputStrategy;
        }
        public void Seed(int i)
        {
            V = (float) i;
            X = (float) 2 * i;
            Y = (float) 3 * i;
            Z = OutputStrategy(V, X, Y);
        }
    }
```

and I have the NuML code to set up the source values and predict an answer for an arbitrary new data point:

NB: The output strategy is a simple 2 * A + 1. I've tried it with multivariate analysis and the prediction is further away

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Generate sample data
        int sampleSize = 1000;
        Sample[] samples = new Sample[sampleSize];
        Func<float, float, float, float> outputStrategy = (A, B, C) => 2 * A + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
        {
            samples[i] = new Sample(outputStrategy);
            samples[i].Seed(i);
        }

        // calculate model
        var generator = new LinearRegressionGenerator();
        var descriptor = Descriptor.New("Samples")
            .With("V").As(typeof(float))
            .With("X").As(typeof(float))
            .With("Y").As(typeof(float))
            .Learn("Z").As(typeof(float));
        generator.Descriptor = descriptor;
        var model = Learner.Learn(samples, 0.6, 50, generator);

        // Use prediction
        var targetSample = new Sample(outputStrategy);
        targetSample.Seed(sampleSize + 1);
        var predictedSample = model.Model.Predict(targetSample);
        var predictedValue = predictedSample.Z;
        var actualValue = outputStrategy(targetSample.V, targetSample.X, targetSample.Y);
        Console.Write("Predicted Value = {0}, Actual Value = {1}, Difference = {2} {3:0.00}%", predictedValue, actualValue, actualValue - predictedValue, (decimal) (actualValue - predictedValue) / (decimal) predictedValue * 100M);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

This gives a difference of about 0.5% which considering the line is completely straight was surprising. I have tried using different % of the dataset for training and number of iterations of the model but it makes no difference to the output.

If I use even a more slightly more complicated model I get much worse predictive capabilities. If I use logistic regression, the predicted output of Z is always 1?!